# How can I reference a nested component via CSS in Flex 3?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3

Using CSS, how would I reference the Button component?  FWIW, I'm using Flex 3.x SDK.

```
<mx:HBox id="myHBox" styleName="myHBox">
   <mx:Button label="Test"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flex 3.x you cannot access it via css without using a type selector like so:

```
Button{
  someProp:someVal;
}
```

but that would apply to every instance of the button class.

Flex 4.x has a better implementation of css selectors and you could access it via its parent like so:

```
#myHbox s|Button{
  someProp:someVal;
}
```

Comment: It's a css namespace:  http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/CSS+Namespaces+Support

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this (amongst other things) is a limitation in Flex 3.x.  Fortunately, it works as one would imagine in Flex 4:

http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/new-css-selectors-are-supported-in-the-flex-4-trunk/